# Изменить стиль элемента соседнего блока на CSS

Tags: css

Можно ли изменить стиль элемента соседнего блока на CSS без JS?
Если блок **txt** добавить в **parent2** то всё работает...

```css
#txt {
  display: none;
}

#r1:checked #txt {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent2">
    <input type="radio" name "i1" id="r1">
    
    <input type="radio" name "i1" id="r2">
    
  </div>
  <div id="txt">bla-bla-bla</div>
</div>
```

По нажатию на радиокнопку появляется блок с текстом. Но этот блок находится вне общего родителя.

Comment: а можно поподробнее что нужно, а то из вопроса не очень понятно (вернее очень непонятно)

Comment: Нет. В теории могло  бы сработать `.parent2:has(#r1:checked) + #txt`, но `:has` нигде не поддерживается. Так что только менять вёрстку.

Comment: По нажатию на радиокнопку появляется блок с текстом. Но этот блок находится вне общего родителя...

Comment: @PavelDAS Предположу, что если блок находится не соседний и не вложенный, поменять стили без  js  не получится. Что мешает на  js добавить класс  hidden  блоку или наоборот убрать его в случае активного или не активного чекбокса?

Comment: @WalkMess, спасибо, придётся js использовать...